# LNK2019 problems when trying to get custom window frame in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, lnk2019

I want a custom window frame for an app I've made in Qt 5.4 with QML.Before implementing it on my main project, I tried the following on a default application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    //engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QDeclarativeView view;
    viewsetWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint
           | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint
           | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint
           | Qt::Window);
    view.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    view.setMaximumHeight(640);
    view.setMaximumWidth(350);
    view.viewport()->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets
QT += core gui widgets quick
QT += network

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

The errors:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler::QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler(void)" (__imp_??0QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'qmlEnableDebuggingHelper''(void)" (??__EqmlEnableDebuggingHelper@@YAXXZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QDeclarativeView::QDeclarativeView(class QWidget *)" (__imp_??0QDeclarativeView@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function main

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QDeclarativeView::~QDeclarativeView(void)" (__imp_??1QDeclarativeView@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

I know this is related to my .pro file but not too good in understanding LNk errors, I've tried different things but no progress, till now. How to fix this?

Comment: For what concerns `Quick2`, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781802/transparent-widget-with-qtquick-2-0) and also to [this forum discussion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23995) about the usage of `QQuickView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the pro file:

```
QT += declarative
```

[From the doc:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qt-quick-1)

> For the purposes of porting older applications, the QtDeclarative
>   module is still available in Qt 5 but has been renamed to Qt Quick 1.
>   Applications that required Qt Quick 1 specific API (e.g.
>   QDeclarativeView or QDeclarativeItem and the Graphics View
>   integration) can use this module. Note that new applications should
>   use the new Qt QML and Qt Quick modules instead.
>
> To use the Qt Quick 1 module, add "declarative" to your qmake .pro
>   file:
>
> Required header files can be included as follows:

```
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeItem>
```

Also:

> All classes that were previously in the QtDeclarative module have been
>   moved into the Qt QML and Qt Quick modules, and their class names have
>   been changed to reflect their new module locations. The class name
>   changes are as follows:
>
> ... QDeclarativeView -> QQuickView

But:

> (The QtDeclarative module is still available to developers as the Qt
>   Quick 1 module, as discussed below. However, it should not be used for
>   new applications.)

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie maybe this my answer will be useful for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870559/restore-minimized-frameless-window-in-qml

Comment: Hah! Thanks again. By the way, I'm now trying to figure how to minimize the window, when a button is pressed in qml lol.I would be awesome if you can point me in the right direction.